# Add new element to each object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have this:

```
var names = [
{
    "First": "Jim",
    "Last": "Jones"
},
{
    "First": "Mike",
    "Last": "Smith"
},
{
    "First": "Joe",
    "Last": "Johnson"
}
]
```

And I now want to add a "Middle" field with a middle name to each object in that array. Can I do it simply? Push doesn't seem to exist in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just assign it, using `obj.Middle` or `obj["Middle"]`:

But if you want the ordering to be really the middle one, then it can't, because ES6 property names are ordered first by numbers (as strings) and then by insertion order.

```js
var names = [{
    "First": "Jim",
    "Last": "Jones"
  },
  {
    "First": "Mike",
    "Last": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "First": "Joe",
    "Last": "Johnson"
  }
];

names.forEach(obj => obj.Middle = "N/A");
console.log(names);
```

Comment: Nice and simple and doesn't require mapping to a new array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.map` method on the `Array` object to create a new array without mutating the original array.

`push` adds a new entry to the array and does not update the item.

```js
var names = [{
    "First": "Jim",
    "Last": "Jones"
  },
  {
    "First": "Mike",
    "Last": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "First": "Joe",
    "Last": "Johnson"
  }
];

var updatedNames = names.map(name => {
  const {
    First,
    Last
  } = name;
  
  return {
    First,
    Last,
    Middle : 'middle name'
  }
});

console.log(updatedNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

map method of the javascript can be used to achieve this,

```
let newNamesArray = names.map(name => {
  return {
    ...name,
    "Middle": "The middle name you want"
  }
});
names = newNamesArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it by using `.assign` method of `Object` and `.map` of `Array` this way

```js
var names = [{
    "First": "Jim",
    "Last": "Jones"
  },
  {
    "First": "Mike",
    "Last": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "First": "Joe",
    "Last": "Johnson"
  }
];

names = names.map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj, {Middle: "N/A"}));
console.log(names);
```

**Note that is very useful if you want to separate the obtained names to the old ones** For that, instead of affecting the result to names simply create another variable

```
let anotherNames = names.map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj, {Middle: "N/A"}));
```

As I said the anotherNames and Names variable are **totally independent**